# hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.call() is applicable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting "No signature" error when the body() method calls in my pipeline groovy script

I was using Jenkins shared library for pipeline project. I have configured the shared library in my local Jenkins. When I tried to hit my shared library, it is getting called properly but I am not able to resolve the parameters values which is coming in my shared library `call()` method.

**My Share Library code (`myDeliveryPipeline.groovy`)**

```
def call(body) {
    println(body)

// evaluate the body block, and collect configuration into the object
    def pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    println (pipelineParams.BRANCH)
    println 'Map'
    println body
    println 'pipelineParams'
    println pipelineParams

    println 'Start pipeline steps'
   // our complete declarative pipeline can go in here

    pipeline {
        agent any

        // Stage checkout git
        stages {
            stage('checkout git') {
                steps{
                    git branch: 'master', url:'MY_GIT_HUB_URL'
                }
            }
        //checkout git ends

        // stage build
        stage('build') {
            steps{
                script{
                    if(isUnix()){
                            sh 'mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
                        }
                        else{
                            bat('mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        // stage build ends

         // stage Test
         stage ('test') {
            steps{
                script{
                    if('yes' == 'yes'){
                        if(isUnix()){
                            parallel (
                                "unit tests": { sh 'mvn test' },
                                "integration tests": { sh 'mvn integration-test' }
                                )
                            }
                        else{
                            parallel (
                                "unit tests": { bat('mvn test')},
                                "integration tests": { bat('mvn integration-test')}
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
             // stage Test Ends
        }
        post {
            failure {
                mail to: 'MAIL_ID@gmail.com', subject: 'Pipeline failed', body: "${env.BUILD_URL}"
            }
            success{
                println "SUCCESS"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Jenkins File**

```
properties ([
        parameters([
            string(name: 'BRANCH', defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Branch to build'),
            choice(name: 'RUN_TEST', choices: ['yes', 'no'], description: 'Run test while build'),
            booleanParam(name: 'MAIL_TRIGGER', defaultValue: true, description: 'mail to be triggred'),
            string(name: 'EMAIL', defaultValue: 'MY_EMAIL@gmail.com', description: 'Mail to be notified')
        ])
   ])

@Library('my-pipeline-library') _

myDeliveryPipeline(BRANCH:params.BRANCH, RUN_TEST:params.RUN_TEST, MAIL_TRIGGER:params.MAIL_TRIGGER, EMAIL:params.EMAIL)
```

**Logs from my job**

```
     > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 2fdeb821e0ecec40e53b2e0bdd6608840914422b # timeout=10
    [Pipeline] properties

    [Pipeline] echo

    {BRANCH=master, RUN_TEST=yes, MAIL_TRIGGER=true, EMAIL=MAIL_ID@gmail.com}


    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
        at myDeliveryPipeline.call(C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestJenkinsFile\builds\43\libs\my-pipeline-library\vars\myDeliveryPipeline.groovy:10)
        at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:14)
        at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor255.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the shared library file `vars/myDeliveryPipeline.groovy`, the signature of  `call` is `call(<Closure>)`.

However, I see you are calling it  as it is `call(<Map>)`.

Thus, call it :

```
myDeliveryPipeline {
  BRANCH=params.BRANCH
  RUN_TEST=params.RUN_TEST
  MAIL_TRIGGER=params.MAIL_TRIGGER
  EMAIL=params.EMAIL
}
```

Instead of : `myDeliveryPipeline(BRANCH:params.BRANCH, RUN_TEST:params.RUN_TEST, MAIL_TRIGGER:params.MAIL_TRIGGER, EMAIL:params.EMAIL)` .

By now, the signature is fixed, but I can see that you override the DELEGATION of the closure (body) from Jenkins to a Map. As consequence, `params` is undefined.

Thus, I suggest to overload `call(<Closure>)` with `call(<Map>, <Closure>)`.

```
def call(body) {
  call([:], body)
}

def call(pipelineParams, body) {
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()
    //...
}
```

By now, the call can be :

```
myDeliveryPipeline(
 BRANCH:params.BRANCH,
 RUN_TEST:params.RUN_TEST,
 MAIL_TRIGGER:params.MAIL_TRIGGER,
 EMAIL:params.EMAIL
) {}
```

Do not forget the last `{}`.

Briefly :

- If you want to inject pipeline variables (i.e: params,...) , inject them in `Map` using signature `myDeliveryPipeline(Map,Closure)` even if the closure is empty.
- If you are not depending on Pipeline variables, you can use `Closure` by using the signature `myDeliveryPipeline(Closure)`